# Font-awesome 5.13.0 with react

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

I'm trying to use Font-Awesome 5.13.0 in a react.js application, is there a way to use the icons like this:

```
<i className="fas fa-tachometer-alt fa-fw "></i>
```

Instead of using the 'official react way' like:

```
import { faHome } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: include the CDN and you are done `<script  src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/js/all.js"></script>
`

Comment: @TemaniAfif do i need to install via npm anything? or just add the script

Comment: simply add the script

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks a lot, thats the simplest solution, it works

Answer (score 2):

You can hotlink the css from a CDN like https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/ (remember to configure CSP)

Another option is to import the Font Awesome css from node modules

```
import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
```

You'll need to have your build tool configured to load sass/css files like so for webpack

```
{
    test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,
    use: ['style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader']
},
```

You'll need to have your build tool configured to load font files like so for webpack

```
{
    test: /\.(svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$/,
    use: ['file-loader']
}
```